# cross compile gdb server to mips arc

Tags: linux, compile, cross-platform, mips

Hi Im trying to crosscompile gdbserver to mips architecture . I'v donwloaded gdb 7-12 and after running configure

```
./configure --host=mips-linux-gnu
```

Im getting an error

```
Makefile:263: recipe for target 'linux-mips-low.o' failed
make: *** [linux-mips-low.o] Error 1
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this error since google does not give me an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on the follow link, they teach to cross compile and use the gdb for powerpc processor architecture, i had used the same method to cross compile to ARM.

https://www.linux.com/news/remote-cross-target-debugging-gdb-and-gdbserver

in my case, using the above tutorial, what i did was:

`./configure --prefix=~/build-workplace/gdb/final --host=arm-none-linux CC=/*arm-sysroot*/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc AR=/*arm-sysroot*/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar RANLIB=/*arm-sysroot*/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib`

thanks and best regards.

Comment: Is there something at that site that addresses the specific problem the OP is having?  If so, could you summarize it here?

Comment: Sure Adam, the site is a tutorial to cross compile the gdb server. 
But i will edit and summarize the steps in my answer.